# How to sum the values of different columns in a dataframe looping on the variables names

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R (used to work in Stata before) so sorry if the question is too trivial.

I've a dataframe with variables named in a sequential way that follows the following logic: 
q12.X.Y
where X assumes the values from 1 to 9, and Y from 1 to 5

I need to add together the values of the variables of all the q12.X.Y variables  with the Y numbers from 1 to 3 (but NOT those ending with the number 4 or 5)

Ideally I would have written a loop based on the sequential numbers of the variables, namely something like:

```
df$test <- 0
for(i in 1:9){
     for(j in 1:3){
       df$test <- df$test+ df$q12.i.j
      }
 }
```

That obviously do not work.

I also tried with the command "rowSums" and "subset"

```
df$test <- rowSums(subset(df,select= ...)
```

However  I find it a bit cumbersome, as the column numbers are not sequential and i do not want to type the name of all the variables.

Any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: Try `rowSums(df[grep("q12\\.[1-9]\\.[1-3]", names(df))])`

Comment: If all the column names are available, then can create a vector with `paste` `rowSums(df[paste0(rep(paste0("q12.", 1:9, "."), 3), 1:3)])`

Comment: @akrun thank you so much! I tried with grep and it did exactly what I wanted to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` to get the match

```
rowSums(df[grep("q12\\.[1-9]\\.[1-3]", names(df))])
```

or if all the column names are present, then use an exact match by creating the column names with `paste`

```
rowSums(df[paste0(rep(paste0("q12.", 1:9, "."), 3), 1:3)])
```